# Running Windows task scheduler without storing service account username passwords in console application

Tags: c#, service, console, account

I have developed a console application which will read emails from  a group mailbox and ingest it into a web application.
I have a scheduled a windows task scheduler which will run every 5 minutes and will look for unread emails in the group inbox and ingest them into my web application.
The windows scheduler job is run by a service account and my organization has  a policy to not store the service account's username and password in the code.

I tried all possible combinations of these 2 statements but it didn't work.
exchangeServices.UseDefaultCredentials = true;                exchangeServices.Credentials = new WebCredentials   (CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);

But, it works if I use the following line of code (using the username,password in code):
exchangeServices.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");

Comment: You can store the credentials in the app.config file and then [encrypt the credentials section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx). It *looks* like it only works for web.config files, but it will work for app.config files also. You just need to rename it a couple of times.

Comment: @itsme86: thanks a lot for getting back so quickly. I did look into this, but the problem is my organization automatically updates the password for service accounts every 30 days and hence it is not option. I am looking to see if there is a way to not store the credentials of the service account in the application (incuding config file) and use the credentials of the user account authorized to run the job.

Comment: Hate to say it, but you're probably going to have to create some form of human interface every 30 days. Maybe send an email to an ADMIN who can update credentials by reply email. That sounds too much like an exploit to be possible - but I'm interested in what you find, for sure.

Comment: Thanks Shannon for replying. I was able to solve this by unchecking "Do not store password. The task will only have access to local resources" checkbox on the "Task Scheduler". Now, my scheduled job is running fine and I don't have the user name and password in code :) Thanks everyone for all your inputs.